# Wait for user response and then continue script

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I'm working on a small text based multiplayer rpg, and I need to send the user different types of dialog: text, menu or input. When one menu finishes, another menu can start after it. I am using tcp for communication.

```
var name = sendInput(player, "What is your name?");
// sends the packet with "What is your name?" and then waits for a response input packet
var response = sendMenu(player, "Is your name " + name + "?", ["Yes","No"]);
//wait for the menu packet before going next
if(response == "Yes") {
     sendDialog(player, ["test1","test2"]);
     // wait for when they finish the dialog and another menu can happen
     response = sendMenu(player, "Where do you want to start?", ["North","South"]);
} else {
     sendDialog(player, ["goodbye"]);
}
```

I am not sure how to set it up to wait for the response before moving to the next section for different players. I don't want the code to block any other I/O or operations.

Edit: This is what I have come up with (just a test), and it's working somewhat how I want to. Is there anyway to not do this with yields or move the yields so I can just call the functions? When the server receives packet '1', it will start the dialog. Sending a '2' will continue through the dialog. This is similar to how a major production game handled npc dialog scripting on server side.

```
module.exports = {
    parse: function(socket, data) {
        data = data.toString();
        switch (data[0]) {
            case "1": 
                socket.dialog = dialog(socket); 
                socket.dialog.next(); 
                break;
            case "2": 
                socket.dialog.next(); 
                break;
        }        
    }
}

function* dialog(socket) {
    sendDialog(socket, ["first message","second message"]);
    yield;
    sendDialog(socket, ["third message"]);
    yield;
    sendDialog(socket, ["fourth message"]);
    yield;        
}

function sendDialog(socket, message) {
    socket.write(JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

Edit 2: So this is where I am at, it works for just one way dialog, but I want to set it up where I can wait for the response from user like sending them a question inside the dialog function.

```
var name = sendInput(player, "What is your name?");
```

Comment: If you use `socket.io` (for which a game like this is a perfect use-case), the docs will show you the best approach (i.e. event-based, setting up handlers for each user action).

Comment: It's not a web game, but I could setup events for actions with TCP?

Comment: your code doesn't reflects realty . in nodejs , tcp sockets  works like any io operation ( the event loop). the data you receive come from callbacks . and not like you write in your example. see https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: This is possible, and I have seen someone else do it, I'm just not sure how and can't find it again.

Comment: I assume we're talking about one server and several clients? In that case you need a data structure on the server that stores game state, and set up how the server reacts to client input. It's essentially like a chat room, however the messages will change the server's state (and the clients will be restricted in terms of what messages they can send, also based on state). The code you posted suggests that you're expecting this to be simpler and more straightforward than it actually is. You'll need a top-down approach for this, not a bottom-up one.

Comment: Using yield seems to get me close to what I want to do, but not entirely all the way there. Is there an example of what you're talking about @ChrisG

Comment: How exactly do you want this to work? Let's assume you're starting with two-player tic tac toe; are we talking text-input only? What is the other player going to see while you're thinking about your move?

Comment: No think about a mmorpg. You walk up to npc and first box says "hello", next box says "how are you doing?" and third box has a menu "I'm good" or "I'm bad".

Comment: Ok, so we have boxes? How are those displayed? Are you using electron? Something else? Also, real-time choices like that require an event based system, like I told you. While playing the game, picking an option might lead to a 2nd choice right away, but behind the scenes it's still going to be event-based, not "wait for the response". (also, again, and I'm sorry to have to say this: judging from your comments this is going to be *way* more complex than you imagine)

Comment: No I completely understand it, I'm just not exactly sure how to implement it yet. It's not electron, boxes, or anything like that. It's just text: input, menu and dialog. If I was making a tic-tac-toe game I could easily just do a turn counter to accept inputs. It's just a thing I'm trying to learn so I could build out a script essentially that has a dialog flow that a player could move through. I understand it won't be easy, that's why I'm here to get an understanding.

Comment: I keep telling you how to implement it: event and state based. When you say "just text", I assume the player gets a choice like for instance `do you want to (t)alk, (a)ttack or (l)eave?`, something like that? So in other words, the client will be continuously waiting for input, do some basic parsing, then send the choice to the server? Which has to react to multiple players' actions simultaneously?